# How can we imagine Inheritance in memory?

Tags: java, inheritance

Say that we have a superclass `Animal` and a subclass `Dog` that inherits from `Animal`.

Now say that we have created a `Dog` object:

```
Dog dog1 = new Dog();
```

How can we imagine the `dog1` object in memory, are the following two diagrams correct:
[image]

Comment: Idiomatic the first one is correct.

Comment: Your question is is your imagination correct? But honestly IMO both of these visualizations are fine.

Comment: The first one is UML, the second one is "custom", but neither of these is related to how anything is stored in memory.

Comment: If you're talking memory layout in Java, the first one is clearly wrong since its showing two things - in Java, an object has one contiguous section of memory assigned to it which includes the fields of all sub and superclasses. But methods aren't stored per-object, so that is wrong in both diagrams. You can only say that the second diagram is less incorrect than the first diagram.

Comment: "All models are wrong, but some are useful" ;-)

Comment: Second diagram looks more like visualization of Composition rather than Inheritance. Dog is an extension that adds/overrides properties/methods of Animal.